# In Gmail, how can I filter emails by a label applied to previous emails in the same conversation chain?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, spam-prevention

I get a lot of recruiting emails. I do not want to read these emails now, but want to retain them for the future. I have most set to skip my inbox and have a label applied automatically like so:

[image]

However, some still get through and I flag them manually. Many recruiters follow up on their emails 1-3 more times, which I all have to flag manually.

Gmail already associated these emails together though, and even with the label in the inbox:

[image]

I'd like to automatically have these follow-up emails skip my inbox as well.

I tried to create a filter based on the existing label, but it didn't work:

[image]

I've clamped down on every possible avenue I know of to limit / filter these emails but I think my email is just on too many mailing lists at this point, so anything that can save me manual effort going forward will pay dividends. Thank you.